# SVG icons are very large when inlining the SVG to the HTML document

Tags: html, svg, icons

I have essentially this:

```
<body>
  <svg style="display:none">
    <symbol id="mysymb1" viewBox="0 0 200 500">
      <g>
        <path ...></path>
      </g>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="mysymb2" viewBox="0 0 200 500">
      <g>
        <path...></path>
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 25">
      <use xlink:href="#mysymb1"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

My symbols I want to be large during development so I can get in there with some detail, but then when I use them I want them to be like small icons.

The problem is, however, that the icon is showing up extremely large, like over 1000px width and height, causing scrolling and everything. This is pretty much literally the code I have. There's no nested `svg` elements anywhere, and the paths don't extend beyond the 200/500 bounds.

Not sure what to do to make it work so that the icon is small as defined. TBH I always have this problem with SVG and I'm not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the size via CSS. Otherwise the SVG is as large as possible. The `viewBox` is not the relevant part for resizing an SVG in HTML/CSS.

Example code:

```
svg {
    height: 50px;
    width: 20px;
}
```